# After changing disk to dynamic Windows 7 doesn't boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning, dynamic-disk

I shrunk a partition in hard disk.  And there was a unallocated space.  Then I made a partition from that unallocated space.  After doing this whole disk was converted  to dynamic type.

After doing this, I restarted the computer. But Windows 7 doesn't boot. After coming BIOS, there is a blinking cursor.  What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have defined too many partitions on your disk, which is why it got converted to dynamic.

First, get a partition manager that is bootable from CD, such as [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) or [Partition Logic](http://partitionlogic.org.uk/), and delete the partition that you added.

Next, [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) will allow you to backup your data and, if you let it rewrite the partition structure, it will convert your dynamic disk to a basic disk without touching the data.

For a detailed description on using TestDisk see :
[How to non-destructively convert dynamic disks to basic disks](http://mypkb.wordpress.com/2007/03/28/how-to-non-destructively-convert-dynamic-disks-to-basic-disks/).

Just be careful : The smallest mistake could cost you the entire hard disk, requiring re-installing everything again.