# After changing disk to dynamic windows 7 doesn't boot

Tags: windows, partitioning, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After changing disk to dynamic windows 7 doesn't boot](https://superuser.com/questions/242029/after-changing-disk-to-dynamic-windows-7-doesnt-boot)

I shrink a partition in hard disk.And there was a unallocated space.Then I make a partition from that unallocated space.After doing this whole disk was converted  to dynamic type.After doing this I restarted the computer.But windows doesn't boot.After coming bios there is a blinking cursor.Please help me.

Comment: Will you be solving it with programming?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the Windows CD and reinstall windows cleaning up the messed up partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't boot from a dynamic disk.
You need the partition to be active to boot from it.
You can't mark an existing dynamic volume as active.

If you have Windows 7 bootable DVD, you can fix it.

Comment: I have windows 7 bootable DVD but I don't Know how to fix it.

Comment: Hm... I don't have Windows 7 bootable DVD here, but when you start DVD, you will see option Repair windows or something similar. When you click on it, windows shows you options, chose something like Boot repair or similar. Sorry, I can't remember exactly how options are called. I`m sure in one, if you try to back disk to basic all data stored on dinamic partitions will be lost. 
Take a look, is partition where windows stored also dinamic?